# Returning a HTML element as a table

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Using the following code to add a html table to an element. I would like to add a thin, grey line border around cell2, cell3, cell4 & cell5.
I know how to do this for a normal HTML table, but am unsure how to add it in to return it as an innerHTML.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var row0 = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row0.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = "My Table";

var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
var cell2 = row1.insertCell(0);
var cell3 = row1.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML = "Id";
cell3.innerHTML = "1019201" + "</br>";

var row2 = table.insertRow(2);
var cell4 = row2.insertCell(0);
var cell5 = row2.insertCell(1);
cell4.innerHTML = "Name";
cell5.innerHTML = "John Doe" + "</br>";

return table.innerHTML;
```

Comment: where is code which is using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<script>


var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('border', '5px solid black;');
var row0 = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row0.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = "<center><b> <FONT COLOR='FF6600'> Feature Properties </FONT> </b> </center> </br>";

var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
var cell2 = row1.insertCell(0);
var cell3 = row1.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML = "Id";
cell3.innerHTML = "1019201" + "</br>";

var row2 = table.insertRow(2);
var cell4 = row2.insertCell(0);
var cell5 = row2.insertCell(1);
cell4.innerHTML = "Name";
cell5.innerHTML = "John Doe" + "</br>";
var div = document.createElement('divTable');
div.appendChild(table);
document.write(div.innerHTML);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually returning the table, you are only returning the stuff inside the table...

```
return table.innerHTML;
```

The innerHTML won't include the `<table>` element that wraps it.

If you returned the table, you could append it, rather than squirt the HTML into the container.

```
return table;
```

Now you have a table element that you can append to your page...

```
document.getElementById('myelem').appendChild(table);
```

This will solve the cramping issue as the rows won't be orphaned from a table.

You can use CSS to style it all - let me know if you need help on that.